# MODx Local Development Setup/System

Tags: development-environment, modx, modx-revolution

I'm new to MODx, but am quite impressed with its power and flexibility. There's only one caveat, and I'm hoping it's just because I don't know any better.

I'm a frontend dev, and I'm used to building websites of all sizes. But I usually work with files and version control. How would I keep this paradigm with MODx?

From my poking around so far, the only way I found to use an IDE, is to keep static files with my code, to later on copy/paste into MODx Manager. Far from ideal.

I'm aware that a lot of people use an "include" snippet, to include snippets, chunks, etc. Does this work for MODx specific tags? For example, if I include a file as a snippet, and I have a template variable defined in there (or a resource link), would that be properly rendered?

Also, is there a performance hit using a snippet by including a file, vs having the snippet code entered into MODx Manager?

Bottom line, how do you develop sites on MODx? Where do you enter your code? Is there a feature like the "Import HTML" but for snippets and chunks? Is there a way to create new Templates, Documents, Chunks, TVs, etc. without going through the Manager?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a whole documentation site for developing in modx, http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Home - though it mostly concerns extending it - not customization & modification. The short answer is no, there is no version control for your snippets & such, yes, you will have to maintain them manually. [I wish that was not the case]

Most of your php code will go into either a snippet or a plugin, and yes you can include static files in either of those resource types, no, I on't know if there is a performance gain/loss, but I would imagine "no" if your include is cache-able. 
for the includes you can do something like this:

include_once $modx->config['base_path'].'_path_to_my.php_';

-sean

Comment: yeah I've been reading those docs. It's a shame, it'd be nice if the dev process was more dev-friendly, like if all Templates pulled from a set of HTML files in a Templates folder, Snippets from Snippets, etc. then managing the file system would be the same as managing the resources through the Manager

Comment: This is pretty much the only dev pattern I've been able to find recommended online. After developing this way after a couple days, it's not so bad after all, the Manager is a little clunky but oh well

Comment: Something just new - popped up, I haven't tested/previewed it yet, but there is a new release for modx partners that has some kind of template versioning built into it.

Answer (score 1):

There is VersionX for revolution that will allow you version control of chunks, snippets, resources and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is package called [Auditor](http://modx.com/extras/package/auditor) that will allow you to implement version control in Modx

**EDIT**

Sorry just noticed your question is tagged Revolution, Auditor is for Evo. I don't think there's a solution available yet although I believe it is on the Roadmap